# Changing the UUID, Major and Minor values of an iBeacon

Tags: ibeacon

As I understand it, it's possible to change an iBeacon's UUID and Major and Minor values using an SDK provided by the manufacturer. What I do not understand is why you would want to change those values, since you can be pretty sure that the combination of the Major and Minor values is unique. That way you can simply detect all the iBeacons in range and pick the ones you need by those values, instead of scanning for iBeacons that have the Major value that you've set earlier. Would you say that there any downsides to this technique? Does it still allow you to detect iBeacons in the background?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Manufacturers often ship beacons with the same identifier.  Unless requested otherwise, Radius Networks, for example ships all beacons with the identifiers:

ProximityUUID: 2F234454-CF6D-4A0F-ADF2-F4911BA9FFA6 
Major: 1 
Minor: 1

If you have several of these beacons, and you want to cause unique actions to take place when each is detected, you need to change their identifiers so each is unique.

There are several other reasons to change your identifiers:

1. To avoid collisions with other beacon owners who may use the same identifier as you.  You don't want your app to respond as if it is near your beacon when it is in as completely different place near another person's beacons that had the same identifiers.
2. To design a hierarchy of beacon identifiers for background triggering using beacon regions.  This is especially important on iOS, which has limits on when you can launch your app to the background.  By designing your beacons identifiers and app together, you can set up multiple regions that trigger your app to launch into the background and do different things based on a known identifier scheme.
3. On iOS, you can only detect beacons whose UUID is known to you, and there is a max limit of 20 UUIDs per app.  If you need to detect more than 20 beacons, and each have as different UUID, this won't work.

Comment: Is there a way of setting UUID, Major and Minor values without the manufacturer's app?

Comment: This depends on the manufacturer.  Each has a different configuration mechanism.  Some supply a SDK for configuration, some only have an app.